# How to alter monsters for "bounded accuracy"?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, house-rules, homebrew

I was wondering if it's feasible to run 4th edition *without* the continuous inflation of numbers every level, removing the custom of adding half your level to every roll.

The biggest change this would require is downgrading the monster defenses, attacks, and skills. Has anyone done this before? Is there a formula one could use to quickly adjust the monster stats?

Are there other complications someone should consider before doing this in play?

Comment: Hi Gaptooth. I voted to close this question, because as it stands, it's just way too broad. There are any number of approaches one could use in order to make the change you want, and neither have you provided a mechanical reason why you would wish to do so. For example, what specifically about 4th edition would you want to keep that keeps you from moving the the baked in bounded accuracy of 5e? I don't think that given these parameters, a meaningful best answer could be given.

Comment: @keithcurtis Considering the immense size of this task, I highly doubt that more than a few attempts to do this have been made. I can’t imagine this question prompting endless variants, speculation, and so on. 4e is a very complex, refined, mechanical system and achieving a balanced form of bounded accuracy would be very difficult. In short: as long as the answer is asking for already-developed-and-tested rules for this, I think it’s fine.

Comment: These comments make me think I'm missing something crucial. Now that I look at the [DMG Errata file][1], it seems simple to remove the level-based calculation from their stats, by simply adding 1 instead of their level (p7). So a Brute would have 13 AC and +6 to attacks vs. AC, for example. If that's correct, then the table answers my 98% of my question—it doesn't address monster skills and initiative. What am I overlooking?

[1]: https://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdateDMG.pdf

Comment: I've done exactly that in my current campaign, and it works quite well. Actions undertaken: No more +1 every second level to everything for SC. For every 2 levels, monsters lose 1 defense and 1 to-hit (monsters with an odd level lose 1 additional to-hit for smoothness reasons). Damage and hitpoints stay the same. This, of course, removes only half of the AC and to-hit modifiers the monsters (and SC) gain per level, which is exactly right for my purposes. If you want to remove them entirely, you will have to think about ways to handle the other ways SC gain those stats (Equipment and Feats).

Comment: Things to consider: 1.) Basic challenges (i.e. for jumping or stabilizing) remain tougher, which makes actually having a skill more important. 2.) Experience values per monster (if you play with those): higher level monster give too much xp and vice versa. I'm okay-ish with "double xp value every six levels" (down from "double every four levels"). 3.) Remember to reduce level-specific DCs (like monster disguise checks) by an equal amount. 4.) Forgot to mention: Also reduce initiative by 1 every two levels.

Comment: 5.) If your combat participants have a wide range of levels, keep an eye out for auto-hit effects. Example: As a level 1 at-will, Magic Missile kills a level 30 minion without rolling. Sure, that's true for every game, but usually you are expecting a level 30 wizard to fight level 30 minions - not a level 1 wizard to fight level 30 minions. Non-minion enemies can suffer similiary from receiving status effects of lower-level sources. In my campaign, I have created a clunky chance-to-resist-lower-level-auto-hits workaround, but that's only "good enough" because roll20 speeds up resolution.